# CSS display none for li class attribute

Tags: html, css

I have html:
`<li class="widget" data-id="blockid123test">`

How I can show only this data-id? Because I have a lot of them. I tried:

```
#sidebar li:not([data-id='blockid123test']) {
    display: none;  
}
```

This code works ok, but it hides all another `li` classes inside my `.widget` class. How to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#sidebar li.widget:not([data-id="blockid123test"]) {
    display: none;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

To match only elements which match that selector but are also members of the `widget` class… just add a class selector.

```
#sidebar li:not([data-id='blockid123test']).widget
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your class in the css to do so we add a class selector :

```
#sidebar li:not([data-id='blockid123test']).widget {
    display: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css as

```
li:not([data-id='blockid123test']) {
    display: none;  
}
```